# Avoid inserting duplicate records in a table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, duplicates

I want to avoid insertion of duplicate records in 'note' table to prevent the use cases related to duplicate creations. I used below code. I am able to import the personalizations from one course to another course but duplicate data is also coming in 'notes' table. Please guide how to avoid duplicate records in note table.

```
procedure copy_course (i_user_book_id in number,
                       i_course_user_id in number,
                       i_user_id in number,
                       i_from_course_id in number,
                       i_to_course_id in number)
is
insert into note (note_
    id, user_book_id, course_user_id, book_edition_id, book_id, role_type_id, page_id, book_page_number, xcoord, ycoord,
                width, height, share_across_courses, date_created, date_updated, created_by, updated_by, description, share_with_students,text)
    select  note_s.nextval, i_user_book_id, i_course_user_id, book_edition_id, book_id, n.role_type_id, page_id, book_page_number, xcoord, ycoord,
            width, height, share_across_courses, sysdate, sysdate, i_user_id, i_user_id, description, share_with_students,text
    from    note n,
            course_user cu
    where   n.course_user_id = cu.course_user_id
    and     cu.course_id = i_from_course_id;
 update  course
    set     copied_from_course_id = i_from_course_id,
            date_copied = sysdate
    where   course_id = i_to_course_id;
exception
    when others then
        --dbms_output.put_line (sqlerrm);
        null;
end copy_course;
```

Comment: Use an unique constaint on table `note` -> `ALTER TABLE NOTE ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE( column1, column2, ... list all columns which a combination of you want to be unique ... )`. The constraint will prevent from inserting duplicate records and will throw an exception.

Comment: I agree with kordirko 100% - that is by far the best way to address this kind of issues. Use a unique constraint. Not only is this the easiest solution, it will also perform much faster. When you use a unique constraint, Oracle creates an index, so whenever you try to insert a row it can check very quickly if it's a duplicate. Do it "manually" like you are trying to and you will see very poor performance.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting.
Is there any other way also like 'If not exists' ?